# Setting ActionListeners for JButtons according to their color

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a problem with one of my projects. The code below displays the game as it is right now. I need to set different functions when you click on the JButtons, according to the color of the button. For example, if you click the Cyan button, it will play the function CyanBlock(). The colors will change when you play the game.

```
package city;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameBoard extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

// The overall box count in chess board
public static final int squareCount = 64;



public GameBoard(String title) {

    Color defaultColor = Color.WHITE;
    Color darkRedColor = Color.RED;
    Color darkBlueColor = Color.BLUE;
    Color lightBlueColor = Color.CYAN;
    Color lightRedColor = Color.PINK;

    JButton squareButton = null;

    for (int i = 1; i <= squareCount; i++) {
        squareButton = new JButton();
        squareButton.setBackground(defaultColor);
        add(squareButton);
        squareButton.addActionListener(this);

        //Sets the tooltip text of the coordinates of the square
        if (i == 1) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A1");
            squareButton.setActionCommand("A1");
        }

        if (i == 2) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A2");
        }

        if (i == 3) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A3");
        }

        if (i == 4) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A4");
        }

        if (i == 5) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A5");
        }

        if (i == 6) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A6");
        }

        if (i == 7) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A7");
        }

        if (i == 8) {
            squareButton.setToolTipText("A8");
        }

        //Sets the text for the Gate squares
        if (i == 4) {
            squareButton.setText("Red's");
        }

        if (i == 60) {
            squareButton.setText("Blue's");
        }

        if (i == 5 || i == 61) {
            squareButton.setText("Gate");
        }

        //Sets the color for Red Soldiers
        if (i == 1 || i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8) {
            squareButton.setBackground(lightRedColor);
            squareButton.setActionCommand("Red Soldier");
        }

        //Sets the color for the Red Ram
        if (i == 4 || i == 12) {
            squareButton.setBackground(darkRedColor);
            squareButton.setActionCommand("Red Ram");
        }

        //Sets the color for Blue Soldiers
        if (i == 57 || i == 58 || i == 59 || i == 60 || i == 62 || i == 63 || i == 64) {
            squareButton.setBackground(lightBlueColor);
            squareButton.setActionCommand("Blue Soldier");
        }

        //Sets the color for the Blue Ram
        if (i == 53 || i == 61) {
            squareButton.setBackground(darkBlueColor);
            squareButton.setActionCommand("Blue Ram");
        }
    }

    this.setTitle(title); // Setting the title of board
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 18)); // GridLayout will arrange elements in Grid Manager 8 X 8
    this.setSize(650, 650); // Size of the chess board
    this.setVisible(true); // Sets the board visible
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // If you close the window, the program will terminate
    this.setResizable(false); //The window is not resizable anymore ;)
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String action = ae.getActionCommand();
    if(action.equals("A1")){
        System.out.println("lul");
    }

    if (action.equals("Red Soldier")) {
        System.out.println("Red Soldier");
    }
    if (action.equals("Red Ram")) {
        System.out.println("Red Ram");
    }
    if (action.equals("Blue Soldier")) {
        System.out.println("Blue Soldier");
    }
    if (action.equals("Blue Ram")) {
        System.out.println("Blue Ram");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String title = "City - A Two-Player Strategic Game";

    GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard(title); // Creating the instance of gameBoard
}
}
```

Thanks for any help here. Good luck everyone with the same problem as me!

Comment: And the question is? Code seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes, the code works. But I need to change it, so the ActionListeners react to the color of the block, not the position of the block. The colors of each block will change.

Comment: Why not set the `ActionCommand` as the name of the color? And change it as the color changes

Comment: That didn't occur to me. I'll try it, thank you!

Comment: Pleasure, let me know if it works